# Set default group in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

We are running a self hosted instance of gitlab.

Is there a way to set the default group so that all new users are automatically assigned to this group upon account creation?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available when you integrate LDAP (or Active Directory) with GitLab.

### LDAP group links

[LDAP Group Links](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/index.html#manage-group-memberships-via-ldap) let you automatically add/remove users from groups based on their user attributes in LDAP. When users are created or sign in to GitLab, their GitLab group membership is synced against LDAP.

### Without LDAP

If you do not use LDAP/AD, there might be two possible ways to work around this:

#### Use system hooks

You can use [system hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/system_hooks/system_hooks.html) and capture `user_create` events in order to add newly created users to your group.

The disadvantage with this approach is that you'll have to setup a web application to receive these hooks and implement the appropriate logic.

#### Use automation scripts

Alternatively, you can write a script to automate this task periodically. The basic script would get a list of all GitLab users, then a list of all the group members. By comparing those lists, the script can add missing users to the group.

You could run this as a cron job on your GitLab host. Or you might even be able to use something like GitLab [scheduled pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) to run the script as a simple approach.

Your script might leverage the official API, or if you're running the script on the GitLab host itself, you can leverage the gitlab-rails console and script the steps in Ruby.